# Lubuntu 386 18.04 Disks

Tags: udisks

I want to run the Disks disk manager app found in full sized Ubuntu but its not present in my Lubuntu 18.04.
I think Disks is called under the hood udisks. apt-get install usdisk fails as not available. (I find a thing called udisks2 is installed, but I cannot find it in the gui menus.
Is there another gui app that replaces Disks and how do I run it please?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I believe that the application that you are looking for is `gnome-disks` and it is installed via the package `gnome-disk-utility`

from a terminal:

`sudo apt install gnome-disk-utility`

Comment: +1. Yes, Disks is `gnome-disks` :-)

Comment: Wonderful. That's installed and working.   Many Many thanks.